# Blood Obsessed Character with Weaponized Blood?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, class

I though of an idea for a character I'd really like to make and play, but I'm not sure how to go about it, or if it's even possible. So far I've only played Pathfinder and everyone I know plays Pathfinder, so I'd like to stick with that if possible.

The idea, to put it as simple as possible, is a character with weaponized blood. They can bleed on people and cause them damage, or even better, actively use their blood as a weapon in some way. The character is obsessed with blood, doesn't matter who it belongs to. Their blood, enemy blood, everyone.

Now I've tried to find a away to do this, but I haven't really found anything that suits what I'm looking to make. All I've found is the Black-Blooded Oracle who can harm others with their blood (when they take piercing or slashing damage). I've also found some normal and prestige classes with some minor blood based powers or casting abilities (Holy Vindicator's stigmata, Blood Caster, Bloodmage), but they don't really fit what I'm trying to do. I'd prefer a slightly more melee based take if it is possible at all.

I think my best bet would be to be a Black-Blooded Oracle and then look for ways to increase or improve the damage the black blood causes. Then I could just wander though battle spraying blood on everyone For flavor I think I'd go for some Intimidating too. It fits the build I think. I'm willing to multi-class if you think it would fit the build.

So what are your suggestions? Is this character even remotely possible? Any help would be very much appreciated. I've had this idea for a while and haven't been able to make it work.

Comment: It'd be stupidly easy to refluff an Alchemist to say that the 'key ingredient' of his various bombs/extracts is a drop of his own sanguine essence. You may also want to look into the Scarred Witch Doctor archetype - and even combine it with White Haired Witch and refluff the hair-weapon into a 'bloodblade' of some sort.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz please turn that excellent suggestion into an answer where it won't be deleted. Cause comments are.

Answer (score 10):

### Find and Refluff a Class or Ability

The *inflict* line looks like a handy set if you just want 'damaging blood'.  The Dread Necromancer (3.5) class gets an ability called *Charnel Touch* that does small amounts of negative energy damage, why not.

Pick something that you can fluff similarly, preferably with a spell list (spell lists are great, pick the stuff you can refluff as blood-related, take *eschew materials*, ignore the rest).

Play a Black Blade Magus and fluff the black blade as being made out of your blood.

### Write A Class

It's really not hard to write a class.  Keep in mind the basics (level x 2 = overall attack bonus, level x 5 = overall damage per round, level x 10 hp for melee, half those numbers for spellcasters, 3/4 those numbers for half-casters), and just invent some thematic abilities in the style you want.  You want to be a melee blood-user, right?  So this class should a) give you a magical weapon that scales with level (blood slash, or whatever), b) give you some blood-based means of defense that scales with level (blood armour?  fast healing?), c) some wildcard ability(s) (blood teleport?  sanguine fury? rip blood out of someone and save vs death? burning blood defense?) at appropriate levels d) something unique and out of combat, like blood healing or blood scrying or assimilating people's memories by drinking their blood or something.

Call it the Cursed Blood Scion and you're cookin' with gas.

### Cursed Blood Scion

BAB: Good
HD: D10
Fort: Good
Ref: Poor
Will: Poor
Skills: 4+Int

**Cursed Blood Scion**

**1** Cursed Blood, Bloody Frenzy

**2** Tainted Blood, Fearsome Bloody Body

**3** Murderous Blood, Blood Armour

**4** Ancient Prophecy, Taste Taint

**5** Know Blood, Terrifying Mien

**Cursed Blood** - Your blood can be used as a weapon.  Striking someone with your blood, or a weapon formed from your blood, does 1d8 + half your class level as an enhancement bonus + 1.5 your str.  Attacking someone with your blood is an attack action, and you add half your class level as an enhancement bonus to that roll.

**Bloody Frenzy** - If a creature dies or is disabled by lethal damage within 5' of you, you can cover yourself in their blood and go into a frenzy.  You immediately may strike out at another foe within range with your Cursed Blood attack.  This ability triggers even if it isn't your turn and you didn't kill or disable the creature.  The creature may be an ally or an enemy.

**Tainted Blood** - Half the damage from your Cursed Blood ability is now Negative Energy damage.  In addition, creatures must make a fortitude save to avoid being Shaken for the duration of the encounter when struck by your Cursed Blood ability.  Once they make this save, they do not have to make another for 24 hours.

**Fearsome Bloody Body** - Whenever you use your Bloody Frenzy ability, you may immediately make an intimidate check with a +5 bonus vs any enemy with a clear line of sight.  Whenever you succeed on an intimidate check by 10 or more, that foe is Frightened instead of Shaken.

**Murderous Blood** - When loosed from your body, your blood does it's best to kill people.  Whenever you suffer a blow that deals hp damage, your opponent takes an amount of damage equal to half your class level, half slashing, half acid.  If you should be knocked unconscious or killed, your blood forms into a small ooze-like creature and attacks enemies to the best of it's ability (see: Minor Blood Ooze creature entry).  Should you be revived, it immediately returns to your body.

**Blood Armour** - You can form your blood into a protective armour that covers your entire body.  This is a Full-Round Action, and counts as Full Plate Armour with an enhancement bonus equal to half your class level.  It also looks fantastically badass, and gives you a +2 morale bonus to intimidate checks.  You are fatigued as normal for heavy armour if you wear your Blood Armour while running, traveling, or sleeping.

**Ancient Prophecy** - An ancient prophecy sleeps within your veins, doom hidden in the curse that writhes within your blood.  This allows you to tell the future by how cursed and doomed you feel.  Once per day, you may use Divination with a 90% success chance but only to determine the likelihood of bloodshed in any specific circumstance.

**Taste Taint** - If you taste someone's blood, you can tell if they are Evil, Vile, Cursed (as if by Bestow Cursed), a Black Blood Oracle, or otherwise 'cursed' or 'tainted'.  No spell can disguise this, but all you can tell is they are 'tainted' or not - not which specific source of 'taint' it might be.  Tasting spilled blood in combat is a move action if you are the one who spilled it - standard otherwise.

**Know Blood** - If someone whose blood you have tasted is within your class level x 5' of you, you know which square they are in, and which person it is.  You never forget the taste of someone's blood.

**Terrifying Mien** - If you are covered in someone else's blood, you can make a Demoralize intimidate check as a move action, instead of a standard.  If you instead perform it was a full round action, you can attempt to Demoralize every enemy within 30'.

**Walk The Red Road**(8th, paimon blade dance), **The Blood Remembers**(long distance travel through blood), **Sanguine Frenzy**(murder things), **Call of Blood**(make it hard for foes to retreat), **Bloody Allure**(intimidate as diplomacy), **That Red, Red Wine**(better living through blood ingestion), **Cleanse and Purify**(disease removal), **Bloody Grin** (intimidate as will save, 12th), **Blood Shield**, **Birthed In Carnage**, **Hemophage**, **Swim the Red River**, **Smell Blood**, **Evil for Evil, Blood for Blood**, **Death is a Metaphor**, **Blood-Drenched Heritage**, **Your Blood is My Blood**, **Crimson Vampire Knight**, **Flow In A Million Veins, Walk A Thousand Battlefields**

Comment: Hello! OP here! Just wanted to say dude, this class is freaking awesome! It's everything I was looking for! (Plus some really cool flavor stuff too!). Thank you for making this class up! It's totally badass. Just one question: Is this a prestige class? (I assumed is was because there are only 5 levels listed). If yes, what are the pre-requisites for entry?

Comment: @Bloody_Confused Be careful though that Pathfinder is somewhat less open to custom classes than DD3.5 was

Comment: +1 for refluffing. There's no reason not to go that route, and it's quite easy to do.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean the [*Bladebound* Magus](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/archetypes/paizo---magus-archetypes/bladebound)

Comment: If it's the one that gets a Black Blade, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

For *Pathfinder* I recently ran through Book 5 of the Carrion Crown adventure path (Ashes At Dawn), and had fought a Blood Knight (Advanced Beastairy 29). Some of his abilities where:
 
**Blood Drinking**: Any living creature damaged by blood knight's slam attack takes 1 point of constitution damage. If the blood knight grapples an opponent, it deals 1d4 points of Constitution damage each round. The Blood knight gains 5 temp hp for 1 hour each round it drains blood.
**Blood Slick**: A blood knight constantly drips slippery blood in a 10-foot-radius spreaad around itself. The blood slick functions as a *greese* spell with a save DC of 20. Blood knights are immune to to any blood knights blood slick.
**Bonded Armor**: A blood knight always wears the armor in which it died, it cannot remove this armor or exchange it for another suit, if the armor is destroyed, the blood knight is destroyed as well. The blood knight has a +5 saving throw made on behalf of the armor.
**Fountain of Blood**: As a full-round action a blood knight can spray blood from it's armor, each creature within a 15 foot radius is covered in blood and must succeed a DC 20 Fortitude save as though it had ingested the blood knights poisonous blood. The blood fill the area till the blood knights next turn, creatures entering the spray while it persists are subject to its effects. The area coated by the blood sray then becomes coated as though by a blood slick and remains slippery for 6 rounds...
**Poison Blood** Fountain of blood - contact or ingested; save Fort DC 20, frequency 1/round for 6 rounds. Initial effect: 1 Con damage, secondary effect nauseated for 1 minute, cure 2 consecutive saves.

Sources: Carrion Crown Ashes at Dawn 55 & Beastairy 29)

Comment: You could improve this answer by outlining how OP could utilize these abilities, and/or apply them to a PC. Are you implying he should take the level adjustment and *play* a bloodknight?

Comment: I had thought about it, but from what I had read the OP had a pretty good idea of how he wanted to use his own character and all of the suggestions below had only mentioned 3.5e rules. I simply wanted to suggest what I had recently encountered in the Pathfinder world and let him expand upon it from there. Whether or not he should take level adjustments is entirely up to him.